# Why is this Django template context processor not applied for all requests?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've run in to the following Django template context processor problem.

The context processor is defined in `myapp/context_processors.py`:

```
def my_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'foo': 123,
    }
```

It is wired up in settings.py along with the standard Django context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'myproject.myapp.context_processors.my_context_processor',
)
```

The problem I'm encountering is that my_context_processor is not applied for all requests.

It **is not applied** for the following code:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", locals())
```

However, **it is applied** for the following code:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I was under the impression that context processors are applied for ALL requests, not just when `context_instance` is provided.

How do I make my context processors being applied for ALL requests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have answered your own question. It's applied to the responses that use `RequestContext`. It's not applied to the ones that don't.

The way to get it to be applied to all responses is to make sure you always use RequestContext. Or, in Django 1.3+, you can use the new `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`, which creates a RequestContext for you.

Answer (score 3):

Django introduced a new `render` shortcut in Django 1.3 which automatically includes the `RequestContext`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    context = {
        'some_extra_var_for_template': 'value'
    }
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

You can read about it in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

Answer (score 0):

Context processor variables are only available when sending a `RequestContext` object (initialized with the current request) to the template as the `context_instance`.

Comment: Is there any DRY shortcut that I can use to avoid the context_instance boilerplate? I would assume that a quite common scenario is that you'd like the context processor variables to be present for all requests. Say that all views are including a footer which needs the list "linked_sites". "linked_sites" would be provided by a context processor, but I would like to avoid sprinkling my code with context_instance=RequestContext(request) :-)